# How to choose the correct area to fill using buildcycle in asymptote?

Tags: asymptote

I want to fill the area cut off from an ellipse by a line segment.  I want to fill the upper half.  I don't know how to select the upper half.

```
import contour; import graph; size(7cm); 
import patterns;
add("hatch",hatch(2.5mm));
string blank(real x) {return "";} 
real labelscalefactor = 0.5; /* changes label-to-point distance */
pen dps = linewidth(0.7) + fontsize(10); defaultpen(dps); /* default pen style */ 
pen dotstyle = black; /* point style */ 
real xmin = -5.5, xmax = 6.86, ymin = -3.5, ymax = 3.9;  /* image dimensions */

Label laxis; laxis.p = fontsize(10); 
xaxis(xmin, xmax, Ticks(laxis,blank, Step = 1, Size = 2, NoZero),EndArrow(6), above = true); 
yaxis(ymin, ymax, Ticks(laxis, blank, Step = 1, Size = 2, NoZero),EndArrow(6), above = true); /* draws axes; NoZero hides '0' label */ 
 /* draw figures */
real implicitf1 (real x, real y) { return -1+0.1111111111111111*y^2+0.04000000000000001*x^2; } 
guide[][] cf=contour(implicitf1, (xmin,ymin), (xmax,ymax), new real[]{0}, 500);
draw(cf[0][0], linewidth(1)); 
path p1=(-4,-1.8003469843683073)--(5,0); 
draw(p1,linewidth(1));
path p2=buildcycle(p1,cf[0][0]);
 /* dots and labels */
 fill(p2,pattern("hatch"));
dot((-5,0),linewidth(4pt) + dotstyle); 
label("$B$", (-4.960654545454545,0.07629427792915584), NE * labelscalefactor); 
dot((5,0),linewidth(4pt) + dotstyle); 
label("$C$", (5.039709090909089,0.07629427792915584), NE * labelscalefactor); 
dot((0,-3),linewidth(4pt) + dotstyle); 
label("$D$", (0.039527272727271814,-2.927792915531334), NE * labelscalefactor); 
dot((0,3),linewidth(4pt) + dotstyle); 
label("$E$", (0.039527272727271814,3.080381471389646), NE * labelscalefactor); 
dot((-3.999566181385855,-1.8003469843683073),dotstyle); 
label("$A$", (-3.9493818181818185,-1.7070844686648494), NE * labelscalefactor); 
label("$f$", (0.5339272727272717,-1.0395095367847405), NE * labelscalefactor); 
clip((xmin,ymin)--(xmin,ymax)--(xmax,ymax)--(xmax,ymin)--cycle); 
 /* end of picture */
```

With this code I get a figure with lower portion filled.  I want the upper portion filled. How to do this?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reverse the line...

So instead of:

```
path p1=(-4,-1.8003469843683073)--(5,0);
```

you want:

```
path p1=(5,0)--(-4,-1.8003469843683073);
```

this produces

[image]

However, you don't really need `buildcycle` to do what you are doing, or the `contour` library, or to plot the ellipse as a function.  Here is a simpler version that you might find interesting for comparison...

```
settings.outformat="pdf";
defaultpen(fontsize(10pt));
size(377, 0);

import graph;
import patterns;

xaxis("", xmin=-5.5, xmax=6, EndArrow);
yaxis("", ymin=-3.5, ymax=4, EndArrow);

path cf = xscale(5) * yscale(3) * unitcircle;
real a = 2.4;

add("bengal", hatch(2mm, blue));
filldraw(subpath(cf, 0, a) -- cycle, pattern("bengal"));
draw(cf);
draw(point(cf, 0) -- point(cf, a));

dot("$A$", align=SW, point(cf, a));
dot("$B$", align=NW, point(cf, 2));
dot("$C$", align=NE, point(cf, 0));
dot("$D$", align=SE, point(cf, 3));
dot("$E$", align=NE, point(cf, 1));

label("$f$", (1,1), UnFill);
```

which produces:
[image]

### Notes

- Asymptote provides a number of ready-made named paths such as `unitcircle` which you can scale as shown to get an ellipse
- The `unitcircle` path has four "points" along it, starting at 3 o'clock, and measured so that positive is clockwise.  Point 2.4 is 2.4/4 = 0.6 of the way round.
- You can make the shape you want using `subpath` to get part of your path and then closing it back to the start with `-- cycle`.

I can recommend [Charles Staats' tutorial](http://math.uchicago.edu/~cstaats/Charles_Staats_III/Notes_and_papers_files/asymptote_tutorial.pdf).

Comment: I did try changing the order in the buildcycle command, but it didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: I have gone through Charles Staat's tutorial.   I had drawn the figure in geogebra, downloaded as asymptote file and edited it by hand to add shading etc.  I used the ImplicitCurve() command provided by the geogebra. I have similar problem with strophoid.  I have posted the question herehttps://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484915/how-to-choose-the-correct-area-to-correct-area-to-fill-using-build-cycle-in-asym Can you please take a look?

Comment: Correct link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/484915/15036